# Dump thymeleaf object/variable in spring boot controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Is there any way to dump what thymeleaf gonna pass to view but in controller ? 
like in view layer we can acess with `${..} or {#fields.errors}`, but how we inspect / dump it before those variable getting into view layer

is there any way? or by using thymeleaf means you have to dump or debug in view layer ?
Thanks

====

Sample code

```
@GetMapping("/hi")
public String test(@Valid ModelAttribute myModel, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {


    if bindingResult.hasErrors(){
        return "displayErrorDetailsPage"
    }

    return "index"

}
```

Comment: can you share some coding details for this ?

Comment: okay, i've edited my question